# PL/SQL error - invalid file ID

Tags: plsql

Need help with code and error. After executing this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY dir_vezba AS '/home/oracle/vezba';

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE raise_salary
   (p_deptno IN NUMBER, p_per IN NUMBER)
...
END raise_salary;
 /

SET VERIFY OFF
DECLARE
   v_deptno      NUMBER;
   v_per         NUMBER;
   v_oldsalary   employees.salary%TYPE;
   v_newsalary   employees.salary%TYPE;
   file_handle   UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
   f_handle      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
   file_line     VARCHAR2(200);
   f_body        VARCHAR2(200);
   f_line        VARCHAR2(200);
   f_head        VARCHAR2(200);
   file_report   VARCHAR2(150);
   CURSOR emp_cursor IS
      SELECT employee_id, salary
      FROM employees
      WHERE department_id=v_deptno;  
BEGIN
   f_handle:=UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR_VEZBA','POVECANJE_DEP.txt','r');
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(f_handle, file_line);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            EXIT;
      END;     
      v_deptno:=TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(file_line,1,3));
      v_per:=TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(file_line,4,3))/1000;
      file_report:='IZVESTAJ'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY')||TO_CHAR(v_deptno)||'.log';
      file_handle:=UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR_VEZBA', file_report, 'w');
      UTL_FILE.PUTF(file_handle, 'Report generated on: '||SYSDATE||' for department: '||v_deptno);
      UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(file_handle);
      UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(file_handle);
      f_head:='EMPNO    OLD_SALARY    NEW_SALARY';
      UTL_FILE.PUTF(file_handle, f_head);
      UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(file_handle);
      f_line:='=================================';
      UTL_FILE.PUTF(file_handle, f_line);
      UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(file_handle);
      FOR emp_rec IN emp_cursor
      LOOP  
         v_oldsalary:=emp_rec.salary;
         raise_salary(v_deptno, v_per);
         SELECT salary 
           INTO v_newsalary         
           FROM employees
           WHERE employee_id=emp_rec.employee_id;
         f_body:=RPAD(emp_rec.employee_id,9,' ')||RPAD(v_oldsalary,14,' ')||RPAD(v_newsalary,10,' ');
         UTL_FILE.PUTF(file_handle, f_body);
         UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(file_handle);
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;   
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(f_handle);
EXCEPTION 
   WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_OPERATION THEN
      file_report:='IZVESTAJ'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY')||'.bad';
      file_handle:=UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR_VEZBA', file_report, 'w');
      UTL_FILE.PUTF(file_handle, 'NO FILE FOUND');
      UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(file_handle);
END;
/
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-29282: invalid file ID
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 1071
ORA-06512: at line 48
```

Don't know what's the problem with this and what does it means. Besides that, in output I get only one line txt file and nothing else. It should get me 3 text fles with different number of lines in them, depending on the data in tables.

Comment: You have a `UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(file_handle);` within your loop. Don't know if this the source of your problem, but it looks strange.

Comment: Procedure has 13 lines, but the problem is not in there. It works just fine. I also think that the problem is in cursor but don;t know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
  FOR emp_rec IN emp_cursor
  LOOP  
     v_oldsalary:=emp_rec.salary;
     raise_salary(v_deptno, v_per);
     SELECT salary 
       INTO v_newsalary         
       FROM employees
       WHERE employee_id=emp_rec.employee_id;
     f_body:=RPAD(emp_rec.employee_id,9,' ')||RPAD(v_oldsalary,14,' ')||RPAD(v_newsalary,10,' ');
     UTL_FILE.PUTF(file_handle, f_body);
     ----------> UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(file_handle); <-----------
  END LOOP;
```

You close the file while in the loop, so at the next iteration the PUTF will fail.

Comment: At least the line number in the error must have changed?

Comment: Not sure why but if answer does not resolve the issue , why you have accepted this answer

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that the directory name must be in ALL CAPS, but the filename must be all lower case.  I know it sounds stupid, and it probably is, but if no other answer has solved your problem, what have you got to lose by trying this?